# Check value if exist in another table within Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables first table stores user basic Info, the second table stores that user who exist in LDAP directory and third table store common information of both tables.

below is the table structure
[image]

I want name from a table if the value is not matched then check to another table. the desired output looks like.  I tried to achieve this through `UNION` but table have more than 70K records. it's slowing the performance.
Query

```
select Distinct
userInfoID AS 'UserInfoId',
accountName AS 'AccountName',
accountType AS 'AccountType',
privilege AS 'Privilege',
active AS 'IsActive',
org AS 'OrgName',
(L.firstName + ' ' + L.lastName) AS 'Name',
emailId AS 'EmailAddress'
FROM tbl_UserInfo U
LEFT JOIN tbl_ldapUser L ON L.memberId = U.memberId

UNION

select Distinct
userInfoID AS 'UserInfoId',
accountName AS 'AccountName',
accountType AS 'AccountType',
privilege AS 'Privilege',
active AS 'IsActive',
org AS 'OrgName',
(M.firstName + ' ' + M.lastName) AS 'Name',
emailId AS 'EmailAddress'
FROM tbl_UserInfo U
LEFT JOIN tbl_Member M ON M.memberId = U.memberId
```

[image]

Comment: If a query is slow, then show the query in your question.

Comment: I suspect a `NOT EXISTS` will be more performant over a `UNION` which needs to check it 70k~ rows are are distinct. Showing us your attempt will greatly help us help you. Not using images for text is also a must.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i update the question

Comment: Those `DISTINCT`s in the `SELECT`s are just unnecessary overhead. You are already telling the dataset to be `DISTINCT` due to the use of your `UNION`.

Comment: Please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Full index definitions would help also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible to test, however, I suspect this will be far more performant. Firstly I change the `JOIN`s to an `INNER JOIN`, rather than a `LEFT JOIN`. If the row in `tbl_UserInfo` could have no matching rows in both `tbl_ldapUser` and `tbl_Member`, and you still want that row returned, then change the **bottom** query to a `LEFT JOIN` (*not* the top).

I remove both the `DISTINCT`s as these are just additional overhead; you were using `UNION` so you have already stated to the data engine you want distinct rows. I have, however, also changed the `UNION` to a `UNION ALL`, which removes the distinct clause entirely; this is likely why your query was slow as `DISTINCT` can be a very expensive operator.

Finally, I use `EXISTS` instead to check if the row existed in the `tbl_ldapUser` table in the bottom query. This stops a user being returned twice when matched against both tables:

```sql
SELECT userInfoID AS UserInfoId,
       accountName AS AccountName,
       accountType AS AccountType,
       privilege AS Privilege,
       active AS IsActive,
       org AS OrgName,
       (L.firstName + ' ' + L.lastName) AS [Name],
       emailId AS EmailAddress
FROM tbl_UserInfo U
     JOIN tbl_ldapUser L ON L.memberId = U.memberId
UNION ALL
SELECT userInfoID AS UserInfoId,
       accountName AS AccountName,
       accountType AS AccountType,
       privilege AS Privilege,
       active AS IsActive,
       org AS OrgName,
       (M.firstName + ' ' + M.lastName) AS Name,
       emailId AS EmailAddress
FROM tbl_UserInfo U
     JOIN tbl_Member M ON M.memberId = U.memberId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_ldapUser L
                  WHERE L.memberId = U.memberId);
```

Also note I remove the single quotes around the aliases. This is a bad habit. Single quotes are for literal strings, and (even though it is supported) should not be used for aliasing. It can often be confusing to read and people new to the language can think that the syntax works elsewhere. For example `ORDER BY 'UserInfoId'` would ***not*** order by the column aliased using `'UserInfoId'` but by the *literal string* `'UserInfoId'`; meaning the order is completely arbitrary (as every row has the same value, `'UserInfoId'`).

Answer (score 1):

You can union `tbl_ldapUser` and `tbl_Member` before joining, this means that `tbl_UserInfo` will only be queried once.

Also, if there are no duplicates between the two tables then you can change to `UNION ALL` which will be faster.

```sql
SELECT
  u.userInfoID AS UserInfoId,
  u.accountName AS AccountName,
  u.accountType AS AccountType,
  u.privilege AS Privilege,
  u.active AS IsActive,
  u.org AS OrgName,
  (l.firstName + ' ' + l.lastName) AS [Name],
  l.emailId AS EmailAddress
FROM tbl_UserInfo U
JOIN (
    SELECT
        l.firstName,
        l.lastName,
        l.emailId,
        l.memberid
      FROM tbl_ldapUser l
    UNION ALL
-- if there could be duplicates between the two tables change to UNION
    SELECT
        m.firstName,
        m.lastName,
        m.emailId,
        m.memberid
      FROM tbl_Member m
) l ON l.memberId = u.memberId;
```